# how to activate the error trapping mechanism in CATJS?

Tags: testing, mobile, web, frameworks, automation

How do I use the device error trapping mechanism in CATJS (http://catjsteam.github.io/) ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are familiar with the basics (if not you can read about it in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/catjs) or in the [blog](http://catjs.blogspot.co.il/) that has a simple getting started).

That part is new and actually its an OOTB feature.
You'll get to see any thrown errors in the UI console or in the JUnit XML file that is created at each run. This is a great feature if you want to track any errors while you in development on each device or browser that you need to support.

All you have to do is adding an annotation for importing catjs library like so:

in your initial HTML:

```
    <!--
    @[scrap
        @@name catImport
        @@import[
            cat/lib/cat.css
            cat/lib/cat.js
            cat/lib/cat.src.js
        ]
    ]@
    -->
```

And then you just build your project using catjs command-line : `catcli -b`
Now, run the server: `catcli -s`

With that you'll get to load your site using your favorite browser or just use catjs runner command that is: `catcli -r` and it will run your application on any connected device and\or browsers.

The runner's default configuration is also relatively new and not documented just yet. 
Add a runner section to the catproject.json and set it with run like it documented at the runner module. (https://www.npmjs.org/package/catjsrunner)